# Called Api Once and used many component in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular4-httpclient

I have two component Master and MasterDetails and one service name MasterService when first time load master component its working fine but if I navigate to MasterDetails component then I get blank response how to resolve it please suggest me

Master Component

```js
this.masterservice.abc(this.userid).subscribe(res => {
  this.shohinEditData = res;
  // set shohinEdit data in global variable
  this.masterservice.setUserInfo(this.shohinEditData);
}
```

MasterDetails Component

```js
constructor(private masterservice: MasterService){
  this.masterservice.currentuserInfo.subscribe((userInfo) =>{(console.log(userInfo))});
}
```

MasterService

```js
private userInfo = new BehaviorSubject('');
currentuserInfo = this.userInfo.asObservable();


setuserInfo(userInfo: any) {
  this.userInfo.next(userInfo);
}
```

Comment: please share some code as it's really to get the idea of what is actually wrong in your application.

Comment: Also post your app.routing.module

Comment: please see above code

Comment: Please share your code so that every one can understand your question properly.

Comment: @Shubham i don't see it

Comment: I alerady share code above

Comment: shouldn't MasterDetailsComponent be `this.masterservice.currentuserInfo.subscribe((userInfo) =>{(console.log(UserInfo))});
}`

Comment: @Shubham i mean your routing module! If you define your routes wrong you will get blank page

Comment: I have get blank response in console not get blank page

Comment: @Malcor I have write same but get also blank response in console

Comment: One reason might be that your both of the components are getting loaded at once. Do both exist on same route/same html file?

Comment: @ArchitGarg any another way because both component don't exit on same route/same html file

Comment: maybe a typo? you try to print out UserInfo (uppercase U) instead of userInfo

Comment: @k_r_i_d its not a issue

Comment: does `shohinEditData` get value from MasterComponent?

Comment: YES shohinEditData get value from MaterComponent